# CouchDB 2.3 - ¿Compactación automática?

Tags: nosql, couchdb

Parece que la versión CouchDB en su v.2.2 tenía un BUG en la compatación automática ([Si quieres saber más entra aquí](https://github.com/apache/couchdb/issues/1579)), por ende, he actualizado a v.2.3 que salió hace poco tiempo.

He leído la documentación oficial y dice básicamente que hay que configurar los parámetros que determinan cuándo se ejecuta dicha compatación automática [Información en el punto 6.1.3](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/maintenance/compaction.html), esto lo hice en el fichero `local.ini`.

El problema es nunca se lanza la compatación automática y no es problema de los parámetros, ya que configuré un horario correcto y un fragmentado del 1%.

En el enlace que les pasé al principio dice lo siguiente:

> "The daemons/compaction_daemon is responsible for triggering the
>   compaction. It is enabled by default and automatically started. "

He comprobado los servicios con:

`ps -eo 'tty,pid,comm' | grep ^?`

y

`service --status-all` y no veo ninguno con ese nombre.

¿Cómo activo el servicio `daemons/compaction_daemon`?

En este [enlace](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.2.0/config/services.html) me da a entender que debo colocar todos esos parámetros en el fichero `local.ini`, pero no estoy seguro ¿me pueden ayudar por favor?

Configuración del `local.ini`

```
[daemons] 
index_server = {couch_index_server, start_link, []} 
external_manager = {couch_external_manager, start_link, []} 
query_servers = {couch_proc_manager, start_link, []} 
vhosts = {couch_httpd_vhost, start_link, []} 
httpd = {couch_httpd, start_link, []} 
uuids = {couch_uuids, start, []} 
auth_cache = {couch_auth_cache) 
os_daemons = {couch_os_daemons, start_link, []} 
compaction_daemon = {couch_compaction_daemon, start_link, []}


[compaction_daemon] 
; El retraso, en segundos, entre cada comprobación para qué base de datos y índices de vista 
; ; necesita ser compactado 
check_interval = 300 
; ; Si una base de datos o un archivo de índice de vista es más pequeño, este valor (en bytes) 
; ,; La compactación no sucederá. Los archivos muy pequeños siempre tienen una muy alta 
; ; La fragmentación por lo tanto no vale la pena compactarlos. 
 min_file_size = 131072
; 
;[view_compaction]
;keyvalue_buffer_size = 2097152

[compactions]
;db_urls = [{db_fragmentation, "1%"}, {view_fragmentation, "1%"}]
_default = [{db_fragmentation, "1%"}, {view_fragmentation, "1%"}]
```

Comment: En principio solo hay que habilitar la configuración en el bloque [compactions] del local.ini ¿Cual es tu configuración?

Comment: He probado muchas, pero ninguna funciona. Voy a editar la pregunta y colocar la configuración actual.

Comment: Tengo una instalación 2.3.0 con la configuración por defecto habilitada en [compactions] en el local.ini, las bases de datos se compactan de manera automática. En el log aparecen entradas del tipo "Starting compaction for db" en la ventana horaria que tengo definida. ¿Cual es tu sistema operativo?

Comment: ¿Podrías pasarme tu fichero .ini? mientras voy a mirar el log

Comment: No lo puedo creer.. según el log no se está ejecutando por falta de espacio :O